# Improve file transfer performance over VPN

Tags: macos, osx-server, vpn, smb, afp

I have two Apple machines: a server and a client. Both are running the newest builds of macOS Sierra 10.12.6. The “server” machine is running macOS Server running VPN and file sharing. Both machines are connected to Gigabit Internet (1Gbps up and down) but are located thousands of miles apart. The disk read/write speeds on both ends are above 100 MBps (800Mbps).

I connect my client to the server VPN (L2TP) and then file share over AFP. I regularly shuttle large files and folders to the server from the client. However, the highest speed I can get is 5 MBps (40 Mbps) sustained transfer, with a max peak of 12 MBps. If I’m moving files the other way (server to client), but transfers all initiated on the client machine), I can get as high as 10 MBps (80Mbps) sustained transfer. However, I can never get higher than that. Even with the VPN’s overhead, I was hoping to get a higher speed than, at most, 10% of the rated speed.

**My questions are:**

- Is this low speed normal for a VPN (factoring in overhead)?
- What can I do to improve my transfer performance (for large files, not large folders with lots of small files)?

Comment: What is the speed of the internet connections? As over internet you will get much less than disk access speeds

Comment: @Mark Gigabit Internet at both ends, so theoretical maximum data transfer speed (no overhead) is around 120 MBps

Comment: Do you have a symmetric internet connection, so your uplink speed is also 1 Gbit/s? If you perform an internet speed test, does it give you around 100 MByte/s up and down? Note that scp will never give you the full speed due to significant overhead in the underlying ssh, as [explained here](https://serverfault.com/a/559554/317270).

Comment: @not2savvy - Server: 940 Mbps down, 933 Mbps up; Client: 550 Mbps down, 790 Mbps up. All tests conducted on Speedtest.net. Note: I regularly download things at over 800 Mbps on the client, so I’m not worried about speed on either end

Comment: @not2savvy How does SCP relate to AFP? I’m connecting via VPN first to transfer over AFP (appearing as a local disk, not remote)

Comment: @NoahL, I'm sorry, for some reason, I thought I had read that you were using SCP. It seems that AFP – intended for local usage (just like SMB, btw) – suffers a lot from a high latency. It's recommended to use other protocols like (S)FTP that were designed to tolerate high latencies.

Comment: @not2savvy Might something like rsync work?

Comment: In theory, it should work much better than AFP. In my experience, it's quite efficient. Even SCP would be significantly better. :)

Answer (score 3):

AFP (like SMB) is a protocol that was designed for use in local networks. It suffers a lot from the high latencies over WAN.

If possible, use a protocol that was designed to tolerate high latencies, like (S)FTP. Even `scp` or `rsync` should do significantly better.

Answer (score 3):

> Both machines are connected to Gigabit Internet (1Gbps up and down)
> but are located thousands of miles apart.

This doesn't mean that there is a low latency, gig pipe *between* your two sites, it just means there's a gig pipe *from/to* you and your Internet providers.  What happens *after* it leaves your ISPs networks is the critical part of the equation.

#### Properly determining actual bandwidth

There is an excellent (cross platform including Mac, Windows, Linux, iOS, etc.) utility called [iPerf](https://iperf.fr/) that can measure file transfer speeds between points.  For this particular test, it's actually pretty simple:

- at each end-point in your VPN, install the iPerf utility (it's just a single executable binary file)
- on a node at one of the VPN's end-points, run iPerf as a server

  ```
    $ iperf3 -s
  ```
- on another node at the other end of the VPN, run iPerf as a client

  ```
    $ iperf3 - c <hostname/IP>
  ```

You will then get some output similar to below (I'm doing this demo on an internal network):

```
[  4] local 192.168.10.133 port 64041 connected to 192.168.10.113 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   169 MBytes  1.42 Gbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  49.7 MBytes   417 Mbits/sec
....
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   192 MBytes  1.61 Gbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   186 MBytes  1.56 Gbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.63 GBytes  1.40 Gbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  1.63 GBytes  1.40 Gbits/sec                  receiver
```

This will give you an accurate bandwidth measurement accounting for *everything* between your two end-points: satellite up-links, firewalls, routers, etc.    **The bandwidth number you get here is the number you should be looking at to evaluate your transfer speed over VPN.**

#### Reduce Latency

As mentioned previously, AFP and SMB protocols don't perform well in high latency environments.  There are a few things you can do to reduce the latency of your connection:

- Prioritize VPN traffic so it's not slowed down by others using the same Internet connection
- Ensure VPN traffic can use the maximum amount of bandwidth possible.  It's conceivable that your provider/network admin may be [packet or traffic shaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping)  VPN traffic to (as you mentioned) 10% of your available bandwidth.
- Turn off Finder's icons and icon previews and try to always view in List mode(<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>)

#### Turn to the Cloud

If all else fails, a more convenient method to move files is via the cloud.  Services like [OneDrive for Business](https://products.office.com/en-US/onedrive-for-business/compare-onedrive-for-business-plans) gives you a secure method to access your corporate files that synchronized between servers without the latency of a VPN.  If that solution is still to small, you could light up an Azure File Sever or an AWS instance that would act as or synchronize with an on-prem server.