# How can I update my macOS 10.14.6 to latest version?

Tags: macos, catalina, mojave, software-update, error

I am using a 2019 MacBook Pro and I haven't updated the macOS in a while.
Now when I want to update it to the latest version (macOS Catalina).

Every time I try it in System Preferences, I get an error (connection lost or time out).

And I also can't download it from Apple website, because macOS Catalina requires macOS 10.15, and my macOS version is 10.14.

This error occurs on another mac too. What should I do?

Comment: You don’t update from System Preferences, you download Catalina from the App Store. Can you confirm how you’re trying to upgrade?  Go to this link:  https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina/  You should see an “upgrade now” button in the upper right corner of the page.

Comment: @Allan We also see this at work when the system has a certificat / time / other error. OP may need to try recovery or a direct link to kick the App Store to get the correct installer... Since this occurs on several macs, it’s likely a network error as well. I have three parts to my answer as there are three different things that can cause this and we don’t know which affects people, yet.

Comment: That is a direct link. I’m trying to account for not knowing which country the OP is in.  But you get an error in Sys Prefs for a major release upgrade?

Comment: @Allan When I go to this link it gets me to appstore and when I want to download form appstore it brings me to system preferences and downloads it from here and it gives the same error.

Comment: @Allan The update size is more than 8Gb.

Comment: I know how big it is.  I'm trying to figure out the cause of the timeout.  Try forcing it from the store: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314?mt=12

Comment: @Allan how can I force it to download from appstore?

Comment: Just tossing this out there...noticed you were from Iran - I'm vaguely familiar with current/new sanctions against Iran - could it be that products like this got sanctioned?  (I don't know, this is why I'm asking.)

Comment: @Allan when I click "Get" in appstore it gets me to system preferences.

Comment: It allows me to download directly from the App Store.  What about @bmikes suggestion of doing Internet Recovery.  Hold `cmd-opt-r` while booting.

Comment: @Allan maybe it is.

Comment: @Allan but when I use vpn it gives the same error

Comment: @Allan Honestly I am a little bit afraid about that 

Comment: Don't blame you.  Let's assume it's not and let's focus on bandwidth issues.  There's a tool call [iPerf3](https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php) that you can use to check bandwidth speed.  They have public servers you can connect to.   See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394225/monitor-network-connectivity-issues/394251#394251) on how to use.

Comment: @Allan That is a good idea. But do you know how can I force appstore to download macos catalina? And I may use another network to see what happens.

Comment: I don't know why it's taking you to System Preferences, granted, that's one option.  See:  https://support.apple.com/HT201475  You should be able to get it from the App Store for offline installation.

Answer (score 1):

macOS 10.15 ***is*** macOS Catalina. The former is the major version number for macOS, while the latter is the marketing name. Both are essentially the same operating system.

So, you do not need macOS 10.15 to install macOS Catalina. You can go to Mac App Store and search for macOS Catalina, or use the following link to access the macOS Catalina page on the Mac App Store:

https://apps.apple.com/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314

Once you have the page open, click on the **GET** or the [image: iCloud download button] button to download the macOS Catalina installer.

Once downloaded, the installer would launch automatically and guide you through the installation of macOS Catalina 10.15.

Using the Mac App Store would also let you automatically get the current latest update of macOS Catalina, which is macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (6th point release of macOS Catalina).

Should you encounter any issue with installation, make sure you are logged in with an account with administrative access.

Also, make sure you have a backup of your critical data for a very less likely case where the installation may fail.

Comment: Nice link - I still use the old style since that’s what Apple has in their KB - but I’ll probably start using apps.apple.com as it has some better behaviors and I expect Apple to move to it soon on the KB side, too.. More importantly - good tips on backup

Comment: The link is not working anymore on a french Mojave install. Same for https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Use Recovery. Hold Option-Command-R when you restart and install macOS - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314
2. [Install Catalina](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475). Visit this link in Safari - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314?ls=1&mt=12
3. [Install Mojave](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210190). Visit this link in Safari - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?ls=1&mt=12 Then try any update you prefer to get to Catalina.

Comment: When I want to download from appstore it takes me to system preferences and downloads it from here and it gives me the same error.

Comment: @BardiaModaberi Try checking if your Internet connection is working fine, and/or switching to a different network.

Comment: @NimeshNeema My internet is fine. but are you sure that switching the internet would help?

Comment: @BardiaModaberi That should most likely resolve the issue as the macOS Catalina download is accessible from Apple's servers and it doesn't appear to be a server issue.

Comment: @NimeshNeema So what should I do?

Comment: @BardiaModaberi Try again over a different Internet connection. Also try restarting the computer.

Comment: @BardiaModaberi Just because you can get to some internet sites, you might be blocked or filtered from Apple. What happens in Option-Command-R held during the restart? That should handle all the internet... (p.s I put option 1 first since I suspect networking in the end...)

Comment: @bmike Are you sure that option-command-r is a safe way to do it?

Comment: Yes @BardiaModaberi  - we do this all the time at work. I do get a backup any time I have suspicions the mac isn’t working. Yours isn’t working since the update should have just applied without the error spurring you or ask for help, but the update won’t delete anything - just add.