# Internet speed slow on iPhone but fast (at expected speeds) on Android Phone and Windows 10 laptop

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, android

I have 3 devices as listed below. All of them connect to the same WiFi network to access the Internet. I also have access to both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz networks.

Devices:

- iPhone 12 Pro running iOS 16.3
- Oneplus 5T Running Android 10
- Dell XPS 13 running Windows 10 (22H2)

The access point is a Netgear WNDR3700V3 in Access Point mode. All 3 devices are currently connected to the 5 GHz network.

On running speed tests using speed.measurementlab.com and speedtest.net, I'm getting the following results:

- iPhone - Browser Safari - Speed: ~23-24 Mbps
- Android - Browser Firefox - Speed: ~178 Mbps
- Dell Laptop - Browser Firefox - Speed: ~180-195 Mbps

A few additional details:

- All devices are updated for all software and apps (as available).
- Internet connection speed is 350 Mbps. I'm getting the full promised speed when measured using a wired connection directly to the WAN router (for lack of a better term).
- The speeds mentioned above were measured within a two-minute window successive to each other. No other devices are currently using any major bandwidth as the rest of the family is asleep.

The questions I want to answer are:

- Why is the iPhone getting such slow speeds? All 3 devices are around 1 ft of each other and the same distance from the Netgear AP.
- Can I fix it so that the iPhone is able to get similar speeds to the Android Phone and the Laptop?

Edit:
Adding performance measurements using iPerf3 as recommended by @allan
Note: I re-ran the tests for updated numbers. Original test result marked with a **
iOS

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-64.12  sec  48.7 MBytes  6.37 Mbits/sec                  receiver **
[  5]   0.00-55.32  sec   146 MBytes  22.1 Mbits/sec                  receiver

-----------------------------------------------------------
Android

[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  5]   0.00-6.41   sec  48.1 MBytes  63.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver **
[  5]   0.00-10.61  sec   143 MBytes   113 Mbits/sec                  receiver

-----------------------------------------------------------

Raspberry Pi:

[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   176 MBytes   148 Mbits/sec                  receiver**
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   186 MBytes   156 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

As requested by @Andra, tests using native apps on Android and iOS (Used the native Speedtest.net/Ookla apps for now):

iOS:
[image: Speedtest iOS Screenshot - 1]
[image: Speedtest iOS Screenshot - 2]

Android:
[image: Speedtest Android Screenshot - 1]
[image: Speedtest Android Screenshot - 2]

Comment: It's not advisable to test network speeds with servers outside your network as there can be many factors that influence the results.  As it stands, none of your devices give consistent results apart from there being a huge discrepancy between the iPhone and everything else.  That said, it could be due to latency on the WAN at the time you tested.

Comment: Since you have a Windows machine, use [iPerf3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389599/119271) (instructions on the link) to measure bandwidth.  It's available for iOS, macOS, Windows, Android, and FreeBSD/Linux.  Let your Windows machine be the server and test throughput from your iOS and Android devices.  Then post the results.

Comment: @Allan I understand your point but this behaviour is consistent across multiple days and different times of the day. The range is not very different for each device and fairly narrow.

Comment: I'm setting up and will test using iperf3. However, if it was a bandwidth issue, why would the non-ios devices give such high bandwidth? I tested all of them within a 2-minute window. While networks can change dramatically, I highly doubt they will change every time I test.

Edit: Fixed a sentence

Comment: @Allan I tested between the Windows Laptop and the iPhone 12 Pro. Transferred 50M of Data using the iOS app. The speeds are in fact worse:
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-64.12  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-64.12  sec  48.7 MBytes  6.37 Mbits/sec                  receiver

Comment: Android:


Android:
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  5]   0.00-6.41   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[  5]   0.00-6.41   sec  48.1 MBytes  63.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver

Comment: From a Raspberry Pi connected to the router via ethernet:

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   177 MBytes   148 Mbits/sec   36             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   176 MBytes   148 Mbits/sec                  receiver

Comment: The reason for this test is to isolate whether it’s local to you or an external factor.  Can you [edit] your question with the results?  It’s impossible to read in comments.

Comment: could you also try some speedtest measuring app? Instead of speedtest measuring page in the browser.