# Connecting to SMB server from WAN not working

Tags: mac, smb, tunnel

I have a new Mac set up as a home server. I can use the Finder's `Go | Connect to Server...` from local Macs to connect with `smb://my-new-server.local`, but can't connect from outside my LAN. I've tried `smb://myregistereddomain.net` and `smb://xxx.yyy.zzz.www` (my actual static IP address).

I have set my router to forward TCP traffic on port 445 to the server. What am I missing?

Update: have now added forwarding of port 139 but still no luck connecting. Verified that my ISP doesn't block these ports. Could this be something Apple just doesn't allow?

Could a remote user somehow tunnel into my LAN and access the SMB server that way? Where are instructions on doing this?

Comment: This sounds like a router issue, not an Apple one.  Did you forward ports 139 and 445 in the router to your Mac server?

Comment: This is very dangerous.  You really should not be opening your router for incoming SMB connections.  Some ISPs block SMB for your protection.

Comment: So I need port 139 too?

Comment: Why are you assuming it’s an Apple issue?  It works locally which means the server is functioning as it should.  The only problem you’re having a connection that goes *through* your router is failing.  **This is a router/network issue.** @Gilby is correct,  this is quite dangerous and a VPN would be much better, but if you’re not secure on basic port forwarding and NAT traversal, then setting up a VPN (yourself) might be outside your wheelhouse.  Why doesn’t a cloud solution work for you?

Comment: Also, SMB traffic over high latency connections like the Internet is [horrible in terms of performance](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348841/119271)